# Send value to broadcastReceiver Intent Filter

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send extra value to broadcast receiver I am always getting null value. Can somebody help me fix this?

Here is what I have tried:

```java
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
 context.registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);

 Intent intent2 = new Intent("my.action.string");
 intent2.putExtra("value", position);
 context.sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

And in my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```java
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public int value=5;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            value = Integer.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getString("value"));

            if(action.equals("android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"))
            {
                Log.e("Value","+ - "+value);

                CheckDwnloadStatus(value);
            }

        }
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to retrieve the `"value"` extra as a `String`. Is `position` a `String`? Seems like it might be a numerical type.

Comment: Yes. It is integer. Hence I am converting that to integer when receiving it.

Comment: You need to use the `getInt()` method, instead of the `getString()` method.

Comment: but I am adding: "my.action.string"

Comment: That's the action `String` used for `Intent` filtering. It doesn't have anything to do with the types of the extras. Btw, your action `String`s don't match, so the `if` block in your Receiver isn't gong to run for that broadcast.

Comment: So what is the best solution?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but if you want to get the `"value"` extra from the `sendBroadcast()` call you're showing, then change to `getInt()` as I described above, and either change the action `String`s in both places to match, or add another `if` for `"my.action.string"` in the Receiver. Also, if the first code block is the only place you're registering that Receiver, you're not going to get the broadcast from the `sendBroadcast()` call anyway, because the action you're broadcasting doesn't match the `IntentFilter`.

Comment: Did you got a workaround for it? As I also need to pass data with intent filter for registeredBroadcast

Comment: Did you got a workaround for it? As I also need to pass data with intent filter for registeredBroadcast

Answer (score -1):

`position` is your integer. If your are putting an integer with `intent.putExtra()` you should use `intent.getExtras().getInt()`.

> Reason:
>   In `intent.putExtra()` we don't specify the type. System decides which type of Extra we passed. As `position` is known as an `Integer` to the System for retrieving it we need to use `intent.getExtras().getInt()`.